# Matlab cell array function instead of loop

Tags: matlab

```
for i=1:95635
Cross = length(intersect(Array_Bigram(i),Array_test_words));
Union = length(union(Array_Bigram(i),Array_test_words));
JI= Cross/Union;
JacI(i) = JI;
end
```

how I can perform this without the long loop, and will be faster ?

Comment: If `Array_Bigram` is a single word and `Array_test_words` is a `cell` array, then I don't see how this code can be sped up.

Comment: my problem is the complexity... so what to do ? I can not wait 2 years to get the results. is there any mapping solutions ?

Comment: Give us some small representative samples for `Array_Bigram` and `Array_test_words` and the expected output?